# UIImagepickercontroller: converting to low quality video error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am getting inputurl `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` from UIImagepickercontroller's `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`'s method.

```
NSURL *inputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:inputurlstring];
```

I am giving outputurl from this code

```
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"capturedvideo.MOV"];
        NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

I used the following code to get low quality video

```
 - (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL 
    outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL 
    handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler 
    { 

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil]; 
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil]; 
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality]; 
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL; 
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie; 

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) 
    { 
    if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) 
    { 
    printf("completed\n"); 

    } 
    else 
    { 
    printf("error\n"); 
    NSLog(@"error is %@",exportSession.error); 

    } 

    }]; 
}
```

I am getting following error when I use large files only. Because when I use small size video file I did not get any error.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x616d890         
 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/private/var/mobile/Applications/EE1E6701-EED0-4830-BD1D-7366680713C0/tmp//trim.7mL7VS.MOV, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/private/var/mobile/Applications/EE1E6701-EED0-4830-BD1D-7366680713C0/tmp//trim.7mL7VS.MOV, NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x2d1460 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSURL=/private/var/mobile/Applications/EE1E6701-EED0-4830-BD1D-7366680713C0/tmp//trim.7mL7VS.MOV}
```

Comment: Are you trimming the large video? It looks like the trim is being stored in a private folder.

Comment: I am converting to low quality and I am storing in a document directory @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: Why don't you just skip the conversion and set the videoQuality property on the UIImagePickerController to UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow?

Comment: Using this AVFondation method only i get less file size @KasperWelner

Comment: Your code run perfect on my device. Is there any problem about your source video? My video is taken by my device.

Comment: maybe your device is ran out of space?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Sufian I answered to the above question.there is only one change. please see my answer.

Comment: Oh. I was receiving the error because I didn't have "file://" before the path. Btw I'd suggest you to post your solution as an answer and select it, so others may get help from it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above code is perfectly works.  the only change is inputURL.

after I changed  the inputURL to fileURLWithPath:

```
 NSURL *inputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputurlstring];
```

Now its perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

use

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

`AVAssetLibrary` can access your video through its `reference url` only.