# NOt able to convert from MPMediaItem(mp3 song) to NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I have tried following code :

These is my delegate method of MPMediPickerController :

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {

    // Dismiss the media item picker.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",mediaItemCollection,mediaItemCollection.count);

    NSArray *newMediaItem= [mediaItemCollection items];


    MPMediaItem *item=[[newMediaItem objectAtIndex:0] retain];

    [self uploadMusicFile:item];
}
```

This is my custom method MPMediaItem to NSData:

```
- (void) uploadMusicFile:(MPMediaItem *)song
{
    NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];


    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    exporter.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *exportFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                            @"exported.mp4"];

    NSURL *exportURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile] retain];
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL;

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^{
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [documentsDirectory
                                                         stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"exported.mp4"]];

            NSLog(@"%@",data);
     }];
}
```

I am getting "null" in NSlog.

I have also check this post :

[how to convert nsdata to MPMediaitem song iOS Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276484/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-mpmediaitem-song-ios-sdk)

but not getting solution.

I am using xcode 4.6 and ios 6.1.

Can any one tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: What other variables are `nil` in that method?  Check this to find the root cause.

Comment: Your code looks like it's from the following SO question.  Did you read the answers too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276484/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-mpmediaitem-song-ios-sdk

Comment: Yes i already refer it not getting solution

Comment: I used Avexportsession in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872953/when-converting-to-low-quality-video-i-am-getting-error . in that I used  condition for export session is completed or not. check with that . Otherwise print that file data before export session.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: not yet...i find some alternate in my system..

Comment: can u got the solution ????